# Could someone explain what this MS text is trying to convey?

Tags: c++

This [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) contains the following text and code :

If you use the placement new form of the new operator, the form with arguments in addition to the size of the allocation, the compiler does not support a placement form of the delete operator if the constructor throws an exception. For example:

```
// expre_new_Operator2.cpp
// C2660 expected
class A {
public:
   A(int) { throw "Fail!"; }
};
void F(void) {
   try {
      // heap memory pointed to by pa1 will be deallocated
      // by calling ::operator delete(void*).
      A* pa1 = new A(10);
   } catch (...) {
   }
   try {
      // This will call ::operator new(size_t, char*, int).
      // When A::A(int) does a throw, we should call
      // ::operator delete(void*, char*, int) to deallocate
      // the memory pointed to by pa2.  Since
      // ::operator delete(void*, char*, int) has not been implemented,
      // memory will be leaked when the deallocation cannot occur.

      A* pa2 = new(__FILE__, __LINE__) A(20);
   } catch (...) {
   }
}

int main() {
   A a;
}
```

As expressed in the second comment line above, the code emits
C2660:'operator new':no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

Comment: Add `#include <new>` to fix the compile error.

Comment: I included `<new>` and changed `A a;` in `main()` to `F();` but the code still emits C2660.

Answer (score 1):

The upshot is that you always have to implement custom versions of `operator new()` and `operator delete()` in matching pairs. This may at first seem unnecessary, since there is no "placement-delete expression": The only way to destroy a placement-new-constructed object is by manual invocation of the destructor:

```
A * p = new (addr, true, BLUE) A(1, 'a', x);
// uses void * A::operator new(std::size_t, void *, bool, EnumColour) to
// allocate, then invokes constructor A::A(int, char, X) with "this = p".

// ... it's almost over ...

p->~A();  // now it's over!
```

When you look at this, you notice that there is no hypothetical "`delete (addr, true, BLUE) p`". So why would you need to implement `void A::operator delete(void *, bool, EnumColour)`? The answer is precisely the situation described by the text you quoted: When the *constructor* of the object throws an exception, then the compiler automatically tries to invoke the *matching* delete function:

```
struct A {
  A(int, char, X) { throw std::runtime_error("Boo!"); }
  // ...
  static void operator delete(void *, bool, EnumColour) noexcept;
};
```

If *that* function doesn't exist, no function is called at all. Therefore, if you somehow have to take care of cleaning up resources (e.g. move a pool pointer around or update a free list), this will not occur.

Comment: The comment in the code-snippet seems to imply that, but as far as I can discern, it's not at all what the accompanying text is saying. Is the accompanying text simply mistaken?

Comment: @ruakh: That sentence is fairly confused; I'd simply ignore it. They confuse "operator" and "expression", too... well, there is *never* a placement-delete-expression, so this isn't a question about anything being "supported" or not.

Comment: I see what you mean, but . . . I don't know. I think that that sentence makes more sense in the context of the document as a whole, which earlier states, "If you use the operator **new** without any extra arguments, and compile with the /GX, /EHa, or /EHs option, the compiler will generate code to call operator **delete** if the constructor throws an exception." So the point here seems to be that the compiler *won't* call placement delete if placement new uses a constructor that throws an exception.

Comment: @ruakh: You don't need any options for that. If you use the default-`new` expression, the the default `::operator delete()` is invoked in the event of an exception. This is mandated by the standard, and there is nothing MSVC-specific about this.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't know what you mean. This question is specifically about the MSVC documentation, and therefore implicitly about the behavior of MSVC. No one is asking what the standard mandates; that's useful information, obviously -- thank you for providing it -- but MSVC does not always conform perfectly to the standard. The documentation says that you *do* need options to trigger this standard-mandated behavior, and I think it's more likely that this documentation is accurate than that the implementation is conformant in this respect.